# Session scoped bean multiple constructor calls

Tags: jsf-2, constructor, session-bean

I have a session scoped bean (I have checked the imports and they are correct for ManagedBean). There is a main page which checks if the user has been authenticated by calling one of the get methods of the session bean. Upon first view I see that the Session Bean is correctly constructed. If I attempt a login, I see that the correct method is called and the login succeeds. However, when the user is redirected back to the main page the constructor of the session bean is called again. Any ideas?

Comment: do you invalidate your session somewhere in between the process ?

Comment: Please track the `JSESSIONID` cookie and post your observations.

Comment: I had in fact invalidated the session. Thanks for the help